# GORM Query on Multiple Parent and Child Objects With Parent's Property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, parent-child, subset

FYI, feel free to suggest a better title for this. I have the following domain model (we have no control over this):

```
class Foo {
    int id
    String baz
    Date someDate
    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]
    static mapping = {
        id composite: [ "id", "baz" ]
    }
}

class Bar {
    int id
    String baz
    Date someDate
    Foo foo
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["id", "baz", "someDate"]
        columns {
            foo([:]) {
                column name: "id"
                column name: "baz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is: I have a List of Foos and I need to find all Bars where Foo.someDate == Bar.someDate, but only in one query instead of a query for each Foo, with no lazy loading involved.  Also setting Bars to eager fetching is not an option.

For example if this is my data (pseudocode, I'm combining id and baz into simply "id" for simplicity):

```
[
    Foo (someDate:4/1/2013)
        |___ bars: [{someDate:12/4/2012, id:1}, {someDate:4/1/2013, id:2}]
    Foo (someDate:5/10/2012)
        |___ bars: [{someDate:{4/1/2013, id:3}
    Foo (someDate:3/3/2013)
        |___ bars: [{someDate:3/3/2013, id:4}, {someDate:9/5/2013, id:5}]
]
```

I need to return the Bars with id 2 and 4 in one query. I'm really not sure how to approach this.

It could be HQL if necessary but it's preferred to be a GORM query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bar.executeQuery("select b from Bar b join b.foo as f where b.someDate = f.someDate and f in :fooList", [fooList: fooList])
```

Comment: Not GORM, but it's simple and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is the best way to do so, but I think it will give you the result

:)

```
Bar.executeQuery("select b.id from Bar b, Foo f where b.someDate = f.someDate")
```

although I have removed your composite mapping constraints and then tried it, worked for me :)

or using where query:

```
def km = Bar.where {
            foo.someDate==someDate

        }
println(km.list())
```

If you already have foo list then can be filtered through findAll closure:

```
fooList.findAll{it.someDate in it.bars.someDate}
```

:)

Comment: This will query against all Foos though right?  I only want it to query against the list that I currently have.

Comment: yep, I think it will query against all foos
:)

Comment: Ok...not really what I want.  Can this be modified to only query using an existing list of Foos?

Comment: so basically you have some list of foos and want to run a query on that?

Comment: same can be done through where query too, but I think you don't want it but I have added it on the answer, it may help someone else :)

Comment: right, exactly.  i have a list of 3 foo objects for example, and i want to get their Bar objects where each bar object is equal to its parent foo object.  check out the data sample i put in the question.

Comment: Not sure if you want this or not, but I think if you already have foo list then you can use findAll closure for that:

fooList.findAll{it.someDate in it.bars.someDate}

:)

Comment: The problem is that bars is not eagerly fetched, so doing that will do selects for every set of bars in every foo in the list.  That is why i want to do this in one query is so I can avoid doing a query for every set of bars.